# iOS mobile emulator to embed in static HTML5 page

Tags: ios, html, mobile, emulation

How to embed iOS mobile emulator in normal html5 page to preview the website. Please suggest mobile emulator which we can embed in HTML5, no need of desktop emulator or browser extensions.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Why don't you make a video of your app and embed it in your website, if you what to show users any functionality.